# Local cross-sections for free actions of finite groups

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and let
$G$ act freely on $X$. It is well-known that the canonical quotient map $\pi\colon X\to X/G$ onto the orbit space $X/G$ admits local cross-sections.
More precisely, for every $z\in X/G$ there are an open set $U$
in $X/G$ containing $z$, and a continuous function $s\colon U\to X$ such that $\pi\circ s$
is the identity on $U$. In particular, there is an open cover of $X/G$ consisting of sets where a local cross-section can be defined.

**Question:** is there an open cover of $X/G$ *with finite order* consisting of sets where a local cross-section can be defined?

(Recall: an open cover is said to have order at most $d$ if the intersection of any $d+1$ elements of the cover is empty.)

The answer is "yes" if $X$ (or at least $X/G$) is finitistic, so in particular whenever
$X$ has finite covering dimension, and clearly also whenever $X$ is compact. I wonder if it is true in general.